# Mapping hierarchy to diferente table key field in entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, mapping

Once again I need your guidance my friends. I'm in trouble with an error in EF: "ORA-00904: "Extent1"."PERSONID": invalid identifier". I have 3 classes: The parent class "Person" and the children classes "PersonLegal" and "PersonPhysical" simplified below:

```
class Person {
    int Id;
    type SomeProperty;
}

class PersonPhysical : Person {
    type OtherProperty;
}

class PersonLegal : Person {
    type AnotherProperty;
}
```

In fact, Oracle is right to complain because the tables PERSONPHYSICAL and PERSONLEGAL doesn't contains such attribute PERSONID. Instead they have PERSONPHYSICALID and PERSONLEGALID. Person has PERSONID. How do I tell EF that I want to have different column names for that properties in the mapping?

Comment: The Person class has its own table or there are tables only for PERSONPHYSICAL and PERSONLEGAL ?

Comment: Each class has its own table. I'm using a database first aproach because we are migrating a legacy system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DbContext class override method OnModelCreating to define mapping with fluent API and try following code:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Person");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonLegal>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("PersonLegal");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhysical>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("PersonPhysical");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PERSONID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonLegal>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PERSONLEGAL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhysical>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PERSONPHYSICAL");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

And to your DbContext class add 3 propeties:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<PersonLegal> PersonLegals { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<PersonPhysical> PersonPhysicals { get; set; }
```

Comment: This will produce SQL that doesn't match the database schema. The reason is that EF assumes that for each inherited class there are *two* tables. Generate a database from this model to see what I mean.

Comment: No it doesn't. I checked it and the code above produced me 3 tables as I expected. I applied table per class inheritance.

Comment: I tried a similar TPC inheritance scheme with Sql Server and it produces a mess. Looks like the Oracle provider does a better job here.

Comment: Actually I tried it with Sql Server and I got 3 tables as I expected :)

Comment: For me it looks the right way. I'm gonna make some tests here and post if it works or not. thanks.

Comment: In my DBContext inherited class I just have one line: [ modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly); ] wich I suppose its purpose is to tell to EF to look in the current assembly for classes that contains the mapping information for my entities. So my doubt is: I still have to insert those attributes and mapping rules in the DBContext inherited class or should I put it in their respectives classes? (I've tried to put them in the respective classes but Oracle still complains about child tables don't contain the "PERSONID" column)

Comment: If you invoke GetType method on object of proper type then this should be sufficient. Could you post code that caused that exception?

Comment: I got it working just by putting the three attributes in the DBContext inherited class and the other properties in the mapping classes. I got other erros this time with a third class that has a composition with the person class. How should i map the Person class as an attribute in the other class?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You mean relationship?

Comment: Yes. In Person I have a type PersonDocument, but I think there's something missin' in the mappings of these two classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54752/discussion-between-giordano-giuliano-and-mr100).

Comment: It's correct. That approach solved my probles. Thank you very much.